# How to enable 3rd party code to work with Web Services over HTTPS connections that rely on self-signed certificates?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, ssl, https

My goal was to make a web service accessible over an https connection, so I created a self-signed certificate which I thought meant that clients would just need to add the certificate to their Trusted Root Certification Authorities directory in order to avoid this kind of exception:

```
        System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
    Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:
     The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

And if that fails to work, they can always use a ServerCertificateValidationCallback event handler procedure that always returns true.

But the problem I'm currently facing involves 3rd party components running on the server that are supposed to make use of the same web services. For some reason adding the server's own self-signed certificate to its Trusted Root Certification Authorities directory won't do the trick, and the ServerCertificateValidationCallback won't help in this case because I don't have the source code for the 3rd party components.

The web service is supposed to be accessible only over an internal network, so as far as security is concerned, there might not even be a need to make it available over https, but I guess it wouldn't have hurt.

Other than buying a certificate or making the web service available over http, is there anything that I can do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your third party to trust your wsdl url or end point url in their tool or application. They should know how to do that at their end.

And at server side implementation, you need to configure your end point url as **"https without client authentication"** mode.

As per my knowledge, there are 3 option present at server side for http scurity level.

HTTP 
Simple HTTP request will be send to server.
HTTP doesn’t incorporate any security over outgoing and incoming request and response. It's like sending plain text over internet.
That means any third party can interfere our message. Though it uses encoding techniques like UTF-8 etc. but it can be easily decoded.

HTTPS 
HTTPS provide transport level security along with message level security.
Normally it creates a secure session between client and server and transfer request and response message through it in an encrypted format.
HTTPS uses SSL (secure socket layer) certificates to provide security between client and server communication.
In simple language, using certificates means your client knows on which server it's sending data and server knows from which client data is being received. So that it cannot be tampered in between by any third person.
HTTPS always required client side authentication at least. It doesn't matter that you provide it by exporting server certificate or by using self-signed certificate. Depends on your server configuration whether it allows without client authenticated request or not.

Normally there are two options provided to communicate using HTTPS connection.

**HTTPS without client authentication**
Sender application or client needs to trust our WSDL URL in order to communicate with server.
In this approach client don’t have to authenticate its self to server. Only client needs to know, where it's sending data by exporting server certificate or by using self-signed certificate, if server certificate is not available.
It ensures only transport level security

**HTTPS with client authentication**
In this approach you need to exchange SSL certificates between client and server. Without authentication between both, communication is not possible and you will get certification or SSL error at sender application.
These certificates are generated and provided by some authentic vendors. You can also create these certificates at client and server application if it allows.
It also ensures message level security if you use digitally signed certificates along with transport level security.
This is the most secured way to communicate over internet.

Note: Above content is not copied from anywhere. It is prepared by me as per my understanding on http communication protocol. Above options were directly present in SAP PI tool where i have implemented a webservice sometimes ago. I don't have any idea how would it be like in C# ,but concept would be same.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the 3rd party services, have you installed the cert into the User or Local Machine store?

Do you have an IT department where you are working? If so they are probably running an in-house CA. They should be able to issue you a certificate that is already trusted by the machines on the domain.

(Oh and as I'm sure you know, it's never really a good idea to ignore certificate warnings)